# Combining Rows without Unique value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table like this:

```
+------+--------+----------+---------+---------+-----------+---------------+----------+
| Temp | UserID | TaskType | DayType | DayPart | TotalTask | PriorityTasks | LineCost |
+------+--------+----------+---------+---------+-----------+---------------+----------+
|    0 |   1001 |        1 | Weekday | AM      |       155 | NULL          |   125.30 |
|    0 |   1001 |        1 | Weekday | AM      |       155 | 155           |   125.30 |
|    0 |   1001 |        1 | Weekday | PM      |       125 | NULL          |   101.58 |
|    0 |   1001 |        1 | Weekday | PM      |       125 | 125           |   101.58 |
|    1 |   1001 |        1 | Weekday | PM      |       125 | NULL          |    51.81 |
|    0 |   1001 |        1 | Weekend | AM      |        45 | 45            |    97.55 |
|    0 |   1001 |        1 | Weekend | PM      |        54 | NULL          |    54.38 |
|    0 |   1001 |        1 | Weekend | PM      |        54 | 54            |    54.38 |
+------+--------+----------+---------+---------+-----------+---------------+----------+
```

I apparently messed up where I'm attempting to group the Priority tasks as it shouldn't create a separate row when they exist, but instead fill in the value in the current row. So the table should look like this:

```
+------+--------+----------+---------+---------+-----------+---------------+-----------+
| Temp | UserID | TaskType | DayType | DayPart | TotalTask | PriorityTasks | TotalCost |
+------+--------+----------+---------+---------+-----------+---------------+-----------+
|    0 |   1001 |        1 | Weekday | AM      |       155 | 155           |    125.30 |
|    0 |   1001 |        1 | Weekday | PM      |       125 | 125           |    101.58 |
|    1 |   1001 |        1 | Weekday | PM      |       125 | NULL          |     51.81 |
|    0 |   1001 |        1 | Weekend | AM      |        45 | 45            |     97.55 |
|    0 |   1001 |        1 | Weekend | PM      |        54 | 54            |     54.38 |
+------+--------+----------+---------+---------+-----------+---------------+-----------+
```

My query is like the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Temp, UserID, TaskType, DayType, DayPart,
    SUM(TaskCount) OVER (PARTITION BY UserID, TaskType, DayType, DayPart) as TotalTasks,
    CASE WHEN TaskType='PRIORITY' THEN SUM(TaskCount) OVER (PARTITION BY UserID, TaskType, DayType, DayPart) END as PriorityTasks,
    SUM(Cost) OVER (PARTITION BY Temp, UserID, TaskType, DayType, DayPart) as LineCost
FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT Temp, TaskType, UserID, TaskType, DayType = 'Weekend', DayPart, 
            TaskCount=SUM(WeekendTasks), Cost=CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),SUM((CostPerWeek / TasksPerWeek) * WeekendTasks))
        FROM #Temp_CostPerAffiliateByTemp3
        GROUP BY Temp, TaskType, UserID, TaskType, DayPart, CostPerWeek
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Temp, TaskType, UserID, TaskType, DayType = 'Weekday', DayPart, 
            Tasks=SUM(WeekdayTasks), Cost=CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),SUM((CostPerWeek / TasksPerWeek) * WeekdayTasks))
        FROM #Temp_CostPerAffiliateByTemp3
        GROUP BY Temp, TaskType, UserID, TaskType, DayPart, CostPerWeek
    ) AS Y
    WHERE (TaskCount > 0)
) AS X
GROUP BY X.UserID, X.TaskType, X.DayType, X.DayPart, X.Temp, X.TaskCount, X.TaskType, X.Cost
```

I'm guessing its something simple, but everything I searched for references using STUFF which isn't what I"m looking for, or using MAX but I can't use that where I thinks something is missing

```
CASE WHEN TaskType='PRIORITY' THEN SUM(TaskCount) OVER (PARTITION BY UserID, TaskType, DayType, DayPart) END as PriorityTasks
```

But of course I can't do that as I get the error:

*Windowed functions cannot be used in the context of another windowed function or aggregate.
*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why you `UNION ALL` the same result twice?

Comment: @LONG one is for `WeekdayTasks` the other `WeekendTasks`

Comment: oh, I see, looking into again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why does one of them partition by `Temp` and the others do not?

```
SELECT ....
 ...SUM(TaskCount) OVER (PARTITION BY UserID, TaskType, DayType, DayPart) as TotalTasks,
 ...SUM(TaskCount) OVER (PARTITION BY UserID, TaskType, DayType, DayPart) END as PriorityTasks,
 ...SUM(Cost) OVER (PARTITION BY Temp, UserID, TaskType, DayType, DayPart) as LineCost
FROM
...
```

---

It looks like you *could* use `max()`, unless I am missing something...

```
select 
    id = min(id)
  , Temp
  , UserID
  , TaskType
  , DayType
  , DayPart
  , TotalTask
  , PriorityTasks = max(PriorityTasks)
  , LineCost
from t
group by 
    Temp
  , UserID
  , TaskType
  , DayType
  , DayPart
  , TotalTask
  , LineCost
order by min(id)
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/UERVTJ42678

returns:

```
+----+------+--------+----------+---------+---------+-----------+---------------+----------+
| id | Temp | UserID | TaskType | DayType | DayPart | TotalTask | PriorityTasks | LineCost |
+----+------+--------+----------+---------+---------+-----------+---------------+----------+
|  1 |    0 |   1001 |        1 | Weekday | AM      |       155 | 155           | 125,30   |
|  3 |    0 |   1001 |        1 | Weekday | PM      |       125 | 125           | 101,58   |
|  5 |    1 |   1001 |        1 | Weekday | PM      |       125 | NULL          | 51,81    |
|  6 |    0 |   1001 |        1 | Weekend | AM      |        45 | 45            | 97,55    |
|  7 |    0 |   1001 |        1 | Weekend | PM      |        54 | 54            | 54,38    |
+----+------+--------+----------+---------+---------+-----------+---------------+----------+
```

Comment: You saved me again! Thanks for your help, this is exactly what I needed. Knew I must have been missing something straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> declare @foo table([Temp] int, UserID int, TaskType int, DayType varchar(20), 
>                    DayPart varchar(10), TotalTask int, PriorityTasks int, LineCost decimal(10,2));
> insert into @foo values
> (0, 1001, 1, 'Weekday', 'AM', 155, NULL, 125.30),
> (0, 1001, 1, 'Weekday', 'AM', 155,  155, 125.30),
> (0, 1001, 1, 'Weekday', 'PM', 125, NULL, 101.58),
> (0, 1001, 1, 'Weekday', 'PM', 125,  125, 101.58),
> (1, 1001, 1, 'Weekday', 'PM', 125, NULL,  51.81),
> (0, 1001, 1, 'Weekend', 'AM',  45,   45,  97.55),
> (0, 1001, 1, 'Weekend', 'PM',  54, NULL,  54.38),
> (0, 1001, 1, 'Weekend', 'PM',  54,   54,  54.38);
>
> SELECT [Temp], UserID, TaskType, DayType, DayPart, TotalTask, SUM(PriorityTasks) PriorityTasks, LineCost
> FROM   @foo
> GROUP BY [Temp], UserID, TaskType, DayType, DayPart, TotalTask, LineCost
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Temp | UserID | TaskType | DayType | DayPart | TotalTask | PriorityTasks | LineCost
> ---: | -----: | -------: | :------ | :------ | --------: | ------------: | :-------
>    0 |   1001 |        1 | Weekday | AM      |       155 |           155 | 125.30  
>    0 |   1001 |        1 | Weekday | PM      |       125 |           125 | 101.58  
>    0 |   1001 |        1 | Weekend | AM      |        45 |            45 | 97.55   
>    0 |   1001 |        1 | Weekend | PM      |        54 |            54 | 54.38   
>    1 |   1001 |        1 | Weekday | PM      |       125 |          null | 51.81   
>
> Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=9e3ea36dfa1b6f4356313c4b5e187a29)*